# How to access checkbox control inside TabItem from TabItem HeaderTemplate

Tags: wpf

I have `tabItem` which contains one `CheckBox`.Tab inside I am binding one `ListBox`. based on check box checked status I need to control visibility of ListBox. I binded IsChecked property to Visiblity property of `ListBox` by using Boolean to Visibility converter.But It is not changing the status of `Listbox`.

How do I get the control status?

Here I attached my code.

```
<TabItem  Header="Trigger">
    <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <CheckBox x:Name="ui_chbTrigger" IsChecked="{Binding SelectedUiSeries.UiTriggerParameters.HasEcgPulsingConfig, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <Label Content="Trigger" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>

    <Grid >
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource S_ListBoxParameterScan}"
                 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource S_ListBoxItemScanParameter}"
            Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisiblityConverter}, ElementName=ui_chbTrigger}">
            <ListBoxItem>
                <util:HeaderComboBox Style="{DynamicResource S_HeaderComboBoxParameter}" Header="Trigger Type"
                                 ItemsSource="{helpers:EnumBindingHelper {x:Type commonDefs:TriggerType}}"
                                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUiSeries.UiTriggerParameters.TriggerType,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid >
</TabItem>
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Opening tag for TabItem is missing. Please fix it.

Answer (score 0):

How can you reference control from TEMPLATE(your checkbox is in HeaderTemplate)

You can change your code as below

```
      <TabControl>
        <TabItem>
            <TabItem.Header>
                <DockPanel>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="ui_chbTrigger"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>

            <Grid >
                <ListBox Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisiblityConverter}, ElementName=ui_chbTrigger}">
                    <ListBoxItem>
                       <TextBlock>1</TextBlock>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem>
                        <TextBlock>2</TextBlock>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid >
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

Feel free to do the further changes as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CheckBox` is already bound to `SelectedUiSeries.UiTriggerParameters.HasEcgPulsingConfig`.

Instead of trying to do `ElementName`-based Binding, simply bind the other UI element to the same property in the ViewModel:

```
  <ListBox Visibility="{Binding Path=SelectedUiSeries.UiTriggerParameters.HasEcgPulsingConfig,
                                Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisiblityConverter}}"/>
```